# Why same code different results in pycharm and terminal?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I have two py file, first one, `a.py`:

```py
import asyncio


async def async_readline(proc: asyncio.subprocess.Process):
    while proc.returncode is None and not proc.stdout.at_eof():
        out = await proc.stdout.readline()
        print(F"OUT:{out}")

async def main():
    proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
        *["python3", "b.py"],
        stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stdin=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
    )
    tasks = [
        asyncio.create_task(async_readline(proc)),
    ]
    done, pending = await asyncio.wait(
        tasks,
        timeout=4,
        return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED
    )
    [i.cancel() for i in pending]
    print(f"done: {[i.result() for i in done]}")
    if proc.returncode is None:
        proc.kill()
    print(await proc.communicate())

    print(proc.returncode)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

this one is main file.
and another file is `b.py`:

```py
import time


print("start1")
print("start1")
print("start1")
time.sleep(1)
print("start1")
time.sleep(1)
print("start1")
time.sleep(1)
print("start1")
time.sleep(1)
print("start2")
print("start1")
time.sleep(1)
print("start2")
time.sleep(1)
print("start2")
print("start2")

time.sleep(1)
print("end")
```

I run `a.py` with pycharm directly, got the outputs:

```
OUT:b'start1\n'
OUT:b'start1\n'
OUT:b'start1\n'
OUT:b'start1\n'
OUT:b'start1\n'
OUT:b'start1\n'
done: []
(b'start2\nstart1\nstart2\nstart2\nstart2\nend\n', b'')
0
```

Then I used the same command as pycharm in terminal，I get results like this：

```
done: []
(b'start1\nstart1\nstart1\nstart1\nstart1\nstart1\nstart2\nstart1\nstart2\nstart2\nstart2\nend\n', b'')
0
```

Why the results is different?
The **same python interpreter and same code**, but got different outs. I guess the run env has some different, but I can't find it and to repair it.
By the way, I think the pycharm's results is right for my code's logic.

How can I get the same outputs in terminal?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyCharm tends to set [the `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` environment variable](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u), which causes output to be written to stdout immediately, as opposed to being line-buffered. This looks like what's happening here.

Unless you explicitly tell it not to, the value is propagated to your child process.

Comment: Oh ,thanks, I think about it. I use `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 python a.py`, it's work fine!

Comment: `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1` this env has any notes for use it？ Thanks

Comment: I linked the relevant documentation bits. "Force the stdout and stderr streams to be unbuffered. This option has no effect on the stdin stream. Changed in version 3.7: The text layer of the stdout and stderr streams now is unbuffered."

Comment: This document I has seen. The information is a bit lacking.Thanks

Comment: There's more documentation on I/O buffering over at `open()`: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#open

Comment: Thanks！I'll take a look!